# Importing a header file into a catch c++ unit testing framework

Tags: c++, unit-testing, include

I am new to using the Catch c++ unit testing framework.
I'm trying to test a class I've built, let say for example I have two files,
a `cow.cpp` file and a `cow.h` file:
`cow.h`:

```
    class Cow{
      public:
         Cow(std::string name);
         void moo(std::string someWords);
      private:
         std::string name;
    };
```

`cow.cpp`:

```
    Cow::Cow(std::string cowName){
        name = cowName;
    }

    void Cow::moo(std::string someWords){
        std::cout  << "my name is " << name <<" mooo " << someWords <<"\n";
    }
```

now I want to write a test for the class, so I created a test file `testCow.cpp` and included the `catch.h` c++ single header file and the `cow.h` header,
but now when I try to call the method moo I get an undefined call for method, saying it doesn't exist, and the only way to solve this is to copy the entire s++ implementation into the test file, which is really not a good practice...
I am compiling my file using a standard `g++` command , and am using sublime text editor to edit my file, so nothing special to include or bind the files.
Any idea why such thing might happen and how to solve it?

Comment: Post your test-code and the complete error-message please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link to your class's implementation object file.

For example, compiling your class implementation to an object file:

```
g++ -c -o cow.o cow.cpp
```

Now compiling your test program:

```
g++ -o testCow testCow.cpp cow.o
```

When building a program you need to link in all the object files that the program uses.

Alternatively you could get the compiler to do all the compiling and linking in one go by giving it all the source files:

```
g++ -o testCow testCow.cpp cow.cpp
```

But that is not how projects generally do it as it gets impractical as the project grows.